# How to config IIS can access by IP website and hostname website

Tags: iis, webserver

I have default website with lots of virtual directory all clients access to websites by using IP_ADDRESS/virtual_directory

next I have demo site use DNS like [www.demo.company.com](http://www.demo.company.com) I would like to create web site that access by domain name and want to keep default website work so I create
new website binding with

new_website : [www.demo.company.com](http://www.demo.company.com) on *:80

default_website : on *:80

when I access [www.demo.company.com](http://www.demo.company.com) it always go to default_website not new_website. How can I access [www.demo.company.com](http://www.demo.company.com) to new_website and keep default_website runnign with IP_ADDRESS thank you

after looking for solution, IIS support hosting this situation by default
the problem is I config wrong host name

I have
sub1.domain1.com bind to 203.xx.xx.xxx but I bind it as

new_website = [www.sub1.domain.com](http://www.sub1.domain.com) on *:80

and I still have

default_website = *:80

so when I enter website by sub1.domain.com IIS looking for sub1.domain.com and not found, then it match *:80 and go to default_website

Comment: you need to configure virtual hosts in web server such like apache or nginx

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html